# Error with SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Why does the following code cause an error?  I would think the compiler just picks the appropriate overload here?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename ToCheckFor>
struct InterfaceCheck {

    // used by the constexpr function, the function will pass in a pointer to
    // a type with the required types
    template <typename _ToCheckFor, void (_ToCheckFor::*) ()>
    struct InterfaceCheckImplTag {};

    // used to check for the presence of a function print()
    // template <typename T>
    // static constexpr bool function(__attribute__((unused)) void* ptr) {}
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr bool function(__attribute__((unused)) void* ptr) { 
        return false; 
    }
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr bool function (__attribute__((unused))  
         InterfaceCheckImplTag<T, &T::print>* ptr) { 

        return true; 
    }

    constexpr static const bool value = function<ToCheckFor>(nullptr);
};

struct Something {
    void print() { cout << "Something::print()" << endl; }
};

int main() {

    cout << InterfaceCheck<Something>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does replacing the `void*` argument with an ellipsis make the code work as expected?  So the following code works as expected

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename ToCheckFor>
struct InterfaceCheck {

    // used by the constexpr function, the function will pass in a pointer to
    // a type with the required types
    template <typename _ToCheckFor, void (_ToCheckFor::*) ()>
    struct InterfaceCheckImplTag {};

    // used to check for the presence of a function print()
    // template <typename T>
    // static constexpr bool function(__attribute__((unused)) void* ptr) {}
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr bool function(...) { 
        return false; 
    }
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr bool function (__attribute__((unused))  
         InterfaceCheckImplTag<T, &T::print>* ptr) { 

        return true; 
    }

    constexpr static const bool value = function<ToCheckFor>(nullptr);
};

struct Something {
    void print() { cout << "Something::print()" << endl; }
};

int main() {

    cout << InterfaceCheck<Something>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the following code cause an error?

There are two viable choices for the `function` overloads.  Both involve a conversion from the supplied argument, and neither conversion is better than the other:

```
error: call to 'function' is ambiguous
    constexpr static const bool value = function<ToCheckFor>(nullptr);
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:36:13: note: in instantiation of template class 'InterfaceCheck<Something>' requested here
    cout << InterfaceCheck<Something>::value << endl;
            ^
test.cpp:17:27: note: candidate function [with T = Something]
    static constexpr bool function(__attribute__((unused)) void* ptr) { 
                          ^
test.cpp:21:27: note: candidate function [with T = Something]
    static constexpr bool function (__attribute__((unused))
```

Fixing with `function(...)` works because the conversion from anything to `...` is always a "worse" match than anything else (but still legal).  It is a wonderful trick once you know it.

From 13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank]:

> 2. When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
>    - a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis
>        conversion sequence, and
>    - a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion sequence than an ellipsis conversion sequence
>        (13.3.3.1.3).

**History**

I first learned this technique from [Modern C++ Design](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/), section 2.7.  I do not know for sure if this is where it was invented.  But that isn't a bad guess.  The book is now 15 years old, and it is still a good read.

Comment: Nice! Is there anything else about `...` that I should know?  Like where it's used?

Comment: I never use it except in meta-programs like the one in your question.  It can be used at run time.  I have no use for it.  I'll use variadic templates instead (which also involves ellipsis syntax, but is not the same thing).